# Show that $\frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac{(-1)^n}n+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

> How can i prove that $$\frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n} +\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)\tag{$*$}$$

using the **following method** :

> note that : 
>   $(1+x)^{\alpha}=1+\alpha x+\mathcal{O}(x^{2})\quad ( x\to 0) $

\begin{align}
\frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n\sqrt{n+1}}&=\frac{(-1)^n}{n} \left(1+\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n+1}}{n} \right)^{-1}\\
&\text{since } \sqrt{n+1}\sim \sqrt{n} \text{ then } \lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n}=0 \\
&\sim \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}{n} \right)^{-1}\\
&= \frac{(-1)^{n}}n\left(1+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}{n}\right) \right)\\
&= \frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{(-1)^{2n}\sqrt{n}}{n^2}\right) \\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)
\end{align}

- AM i right ?

Comment: You are right! Except one detail: you should only have positive functions inside a big-$O$ expression. So on the third-to-last-line, you should have $O(\frac{\sqrt n}n)$ instead of $O(\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt n}n)$. (The definition of $f(n)=O(g(n))$ is that $|f(n)| \le Cg(n)$ for some $C$; note the absolute value signs. That's why the $g(n)$ needs to always be positive.)

Comment: could you check my other question for big O i'm stuck on some points

Comment: Once again, too much precision is not needed, here the result simply follows from the fact that $(1+x)^{-1}=1+O(x)$ when $x\to0$ (and $\frac1n\sqrt{n+1}\to0$, of course). But please get rid of these awful $\sim$ steps, which do not say what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may write, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n\sqrt{n+1}}&=\frac{(-1)^n}{n} \left(1+\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n+1}}{n} \right)^{-1}\\
&= \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac1n}\: \right)^{-1}\\
&= \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\left(1+\frac1{2n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)\: \right)^{-1}\\
&=  \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)\: \right)^{-1}\\
&=  \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\left(1-\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)\: \right)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)
\end{align}
$$ as wanted.

Comment: one question  please why we work with big notation instead of small one is it because simplfy more for example :  $$f(x)=Ax+Bx^{2}+\mathcal{O}\left(X^{2}\right)=Ax+\mathcal{O}\left(X^2 \right)$$ can't do that with small o

Comment: @Educ Yes it is one of the reasons why we use it.

Comment: Please could you tell me in quick the other reasons

Comment: The other reasons are mainly related to the accuracy one is looking for. As you know a small $o$ is more accurate than a big $O$.

Answer (score 0):

I would initially ignore the
$(-1)^n$
and do

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{1}{n+(-1)^n\sqrt{n+1}}-\frac{1}{n}
&=\frac{n-(n+(-1)^n\sqrt{n+1})}{n(n+(-1)^n\sqrt{n+1})}\\
&=\frac{-(-1)^n\sqrt{n+1}}{n(n+(-1)^n\sqrt{n+1})}\\
&=\frac1{n^{3/2}}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt{1+1/n}}{1+(-1)^n\sqrt{1/n+1/n^2})}\\
\text{so}\\
\big|\frac{1}{n+(-1)^n\sqrt{n+1}}-\frac{1}{n}\big|
&=\frac1{n^{3/2}}\frac{\sqrt{1+1/n}}{1+(-1)^n\sqrt{1/n+1/n^2})}\\
&=O(\frac1{n^{3/2}})\\
\end{array}
$

since
$\sqrt{1+1/n} \to 1$
and
$\sqrt{1/n+1/n^2} \to 0$.