# Show $(-1)^{n}\ln\left[ \frac{n(n+2)}{n^2-n+1} \right]=3\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^2}\right) $

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

> I would like to show that :
>   $$(-1)^{n}\ln\left[ \dfrac{n(n+2)}{n^2-n+1} \right]=3\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^2}\right) $$
>   by starting from the left side and get the right side

**My Proof:**

> Note that :

- $$\ln\left(1+x \right)\underset{ \overset { n \rightarrow +\infty } {} } {=}x+\mathcal{O}\left(x^{2} \right)$$
- $$\dfrac{n(n+2)}{n^2-n+1}=1+\dfrac{3n-1}{n^2-n+1} $$
- $$\dfrac{3n-1}{n^2-n+1}\underset{ \overset { n \rightarrow +\infty } {} } {\sim}\dfrac{3}{n}\underset{ \overset { n \rightarrow +\infty } {} } {\longrightarrow}0$$

\begin{align*}
(-1)^{n}\ln\left[ \dfrac{n(n+2)}{n^2-n+1} \right]&=(-1)^{n}\ln\left[ 1+\dfrac{3n-1}{n^2-n+1} \right]  \\
&\underset{ \overset { n \rightarrow +\infty } {} } {\sim}  (-1)^{n}\ln\left[ 1+\dfrac{3}{n} \right] \\
&= (-1)^{n}\left(\dfrac{3}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\right) \right) \\
&=3\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^2}\right) 
\end{align*}

$$\fbox{$(-1)^{n}\ln\left[ \dfrac{n(n+2)}{n^2-n+1} \right]=3\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^2}\right) $$
   $}$$

- Is my proof correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct. But going along your steps, I would rather write
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{n(n+2)}{n^2-n+1}=\frac{1+\frac2{n}}{1-\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}}=\left(1+\frac2{n}\right)\left(1+\frac1n+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)=1+\frac3n+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)
\end{align}
$$ giving
$$
\ln\left[ \dfrac{n(n+2)}{n^2-n+1} \right]=\frac3n+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)
$$ and
$$
(-1)^n\ln\left[ \dfrac{n(n+2)}{n^2-n+1} \right]=3\frac{(-1)^{n}}n+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right).
$$ I think it is clearer to avoid using the symbol $\sim$ within your equalities.

Comment: but you didn't tell me whether my proof correct or not

Comment: Your proof is correct. But it is clearer to handle only equalities with $O$.

Comment: tell me please in this question how can i avoid  the symbol $\sim$  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858316/show-that-dfrac-1nn-1n-sqrtn1-dfrac-1nn-mathcalo-left

Comment: @Educ No problem, I'll give you answer there.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much